# How to disable identity from the existing column & after adding data , how to enable identity again on the same column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have to do data migration.

For that I have to disable the identity for a column & after adding data there is need to enable that identity again for the same column in SQL Server 2008.

Can someone explain how to do that or is there any other way to do the same task?

Comment: If you have quite a few indexes one your tables you may want to consider dropping and recreating them when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing your migration using normal `INSERT` statements, then you can use [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)*:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT abc ON

INSERT INTO abc (/* Columns */) VALUES
(/* Values */)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT abc OFF
```

If you're using [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), then you'd want the `KEEPIDENTITY` option.

If you're using the SSIS [OLE DB Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) then you'd want to use the Keep Identity option.

If you're using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, then when you've selected appropriate sheets/tables on the **Select Source Tables and Views** page of the wizard, select `Edit Mappings...` and tick the `Enable identity insert` option.

---

*Many people find this option confusingly named, because they assume that they're telling the system what to do - "Please insert identity values" - instead, the sense is "*I'm* going to insert identity values". That's why you turn it **on** before the inserts and **off** afterwards, rather than vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .
But it is not working . I am putting the data in xls format through "SQL Server Import & Export Wizard". I am getting following error report -
- Validating (Error)
 Messages
 * Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "Relative_Id".
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard) 
* Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - RELATIVE_DETAILS" (71)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Comment: If you're using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, then when you've selected appropriate sheets/tables on the "Select Source Tables and Views" page of the wizard, select "Edit Mappings..." and tick the "Enable identity insert" option.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON;

-- Insert Data.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF;
```